# Using docker registry of gitlab, which is installed as docker-container

Tags: gitlab, docker-registry

I have installed a GitLab in a docker container, that works very well.

Now, I would like to use the integrated docker-registry of GitLab.

Now, I tried, adding in `gitlab.rb`:

```
registry_external_url 'https://gitlab.team-f.de'
registry_nginx['enable'] = true
registry_nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = false
registry_nginx['listen_https'] = false
registry_nginx['listen_port'] = 5005
```

Going into the container I can connect to port 5000 and 5005, but those ports do not get exposed!

How can I do this? TIA!

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter? Show errors and steps to reproduce those errors.

Comment: @BMitch I have searched for a howto to do this? I have no idea what to try, without that ... ;)

Comment: Try the documentation https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages/container_registry.html

Comment: @BMitch I have tried (hours ago). But I need a registry listening on http (without tls/certificates), because I am using a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Using a reverse-proxy, I need an extra subdomain for my gitlab-docker-registry.

- gitlab.mydomain.com
- registry.gitlab.mydomain.com

Then I configured in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
    registry_external_url 'https://registry.gitlab.mydomain.com'
    registry_nginx['enable'] = true
    registry_nginx['listen_https'] = false
    registry_nginx['listen_port'] = 5005
    registry_nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = false
```

Now, it works fine. :)